# GA4 BigQuery export. Updating a column based on another table using join that uses a nested, repeated record as join key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I am working with the GA4 BigQuery export and want to update the `items.item_id` field for a few days worth of events. Long story short, we launched a new website and a new format of sku was sent for a few days before we caught it and I want to retroactively fix that for historical reporting purposes. I have a table (call it sku_fwp) that has the correct sku and the incorrect sku that I want to replace in a two column table. I want to write a query that updates all of the skus in my GA4 events table with the correct replacement sku.

I have written a join that properly matches up the new skus with old skus, however, when I try to write an update query I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish what I am after.

One of the main issues I am running into is this query throwing an error regarding the scalar subquery in my join returning multiple elements. I realize why it is wrong, but I need to join on `a.items.item_id = b.fwp` and I am not totally sure how to here. I am pretty confident the issue is with my FROM statement here, but I don't have a ton of experience with UPDATE queries so please let me know where I am going wrong with this.

```
UPDATE `project.table.events_20230809_copy` 
SET items = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      b.fwp AS item_id
    )
    FROM UNNEST(a.items)
  )
FROM `project.table.events_20230809_copy` a left join `dtc_products.sku_fwp` b on (select item_id from unnest(items)) = b.fwp
WHERE true
```